# Need some help for logarithms please!

Tags: logarithms

> Given $\log_2 P=x, \log_2 Q=y,$ and $\log_2 R=z$, determine $$\log_2 \frac{R^2\sqrt{Q}}{P^3}$$ interms of $x,y$ and $z$

Could someone please take me through the steps on how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Just employ $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$, $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$ and $\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$, remembering $\sqrt{a} = a^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody should do this problem for you since it is an assignment for you.

But you should think about the basic properties of logarithms (these are true for any base):

- $\log ab = \log a + \log b$
- $\log a/b = \log a - \log b$
- $\log a^n = n\log a$

Using these, you can break up your expression in terms of the known quantities you are given.